# Find the following indefinite integral including a root and fraction

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following indefinite integral. I know I need to do substitution, but I simply don't know how to do it.

$$\int \:\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try substitution $x=\tan t$. You'll get
$$\int\frac{\tan^2 t}{(1/\cos^2 t)^{3/2}}\frac{dt}{\cos^2 t}=\int \frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos t} dt,$$
which is almost from the table.

Comment: Could you give some more info on how you get to this new integral? Thanks!

Comment: @DitJid, see the edit.